# Save array values into variables PHP

Tags: php

I have an array  `Array ( [email] => pree@ipe.com [mobileNo] => 9999999999 )`

How to store

```
$email = 'pree@ipe.com'
$mobileNo = '9999999999'
```

into variables the key and value

Comment: [`extract()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) does exactly that, but consider if you _really want to_. Leaving them as array keys often makes for much more organized code assuming these values are related...

Answer (score 1):

Just try with [`extract`](http://php.net/extract)

```
$input = array('email' => 'pree@ipe.com', 'mobileNo' => 9999999999);
extract($input);

var_dump($email, $mobileNo);
```

Output:

```
string 'pree@ipe.com' (length=12)
int 9999999999
```